# amortized analysis

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, amortized-analysis

I am trying to find a general solution for the  given A,B,C in dynamic arrays. Those veriables presents factors in the following operations :

given :

- **c_i** the size of the array after operation **O_i (c_0 := 0)**
- **s_i** is the number of elements after operation **O_i (s_0 := 0)**
- **c_i ≥ s_i**

after pushBack: if  **s_i−1 = c_i** , then **c_i = A · s_i**.

after popBack: if  **s_i−1 ≤ c_i−1/B** , then **c_i = C · s_i**.

- (pushBack and popBack are operations in a dynamic arrays ).
- (**s_i = size, c_i = capacity** )

how can i find values for **A , B and C** (in dependence of f) ,
 with for a given **f** with **0 < f < 1** and **A , B, C** with **A > 1** and **B > C > 1** , so that **s_i ≥ f·c_i** ?

**Note** :

it would be nice to add a little explanation of how the results are found,
it's very important to me to understand it.

Comment: The question is somewhat poorly formulated. While it can be followed with some difficulty, it is better if you reformulated it for the benefit of readers who aren't aware of dynamically resizing arrays.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for the note , should i add some links which explain the  dynamical arrays ?

Comment: I'm afraid that won't be enough. Try to reformat your question to make it look like other questions.